# Unit Test - A dictionary with a for loop and try-catch

Tags: loops, dictionary, for-loop

I am new in the Software Development world. Can anyone help me to understand how to create a for loop and a try-catch on a dictionary?

here is the question - 
32 has 6 factors
Create a Dictionary where each factor of 32 is a key to it's corresponding factor (there should be 6 keys)
Use a For Loop to loop through all integer values from 1 to 32. Use a Try Catch to deal with not having a key in the Dictionary. If the key is found Assert that the Key times the Value of the current pair is 32

here is my answer -
        Dim Key1 As Integer
        Dim Value1 As Integer
        Dim Key2 As Integer
        Dim Value2 As Integer
        Dim Key3 As Integer
        Dim Value3 As Integer
        Dim Key4 As Integer
        Dim Value4 As Integer
        Dim Key5 As Integer
        Dim Value5 As Integer
        Dim Key6 As Integer
        Dim Value6 As Integer

```
    Dim result As Integer

    Key1 = 1
    Value1 = 32
    Key2 = 4
    Value2 = 8
    Key3 = 2
    Value3 = 16
    Key4 = 32
    Value4 = 1
    Key5 = 8
    Value5 = 4
    Key6 = 16
    Value6 = 2

    myDictionary.Add(Key1, Value1)
    myDictionary.Add(Key2, Value2)
    myDictionary.Add(Key3, Value3)
    myDictionary.Add(Key4, Value4)
    myDictionary.Add(Key5, Value5)
    myDictionary.Add(Key6, Value6)

    For loopCounter As Integer = 1 To 32
    loopCounter = Key1 And Value1

     If loopCounter > Key6 Then
     Assert.Fail("There is no such key in the dictionary")

     Else

      result = Key1 * Value1

      loopCounter = Key1 + 1 And Value1 + 1

       End If

       Try

       result = Key1 * Value1

       loopCounter = Key6 + 1 And Value6 + 1

       Catch

       Debug.Print(String.Format("KeyNotFoundException"))

       End Try

       Next

       Assert.AreEqual(result, 32, "Key times Value is 32")

       End Sub

       End Class
```

I know that its wrong but don't know how to change it.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be setting loopcounter to anything.  You can reference loopcounter, but it's not advisable to change your index.  re:`For loopCounter As Integer = 1 To 32
    loopCounter = Key1 And Value1`

Comment: thank for answering. do you mean to delete the "loopCounter = Key1 And Value1"? but what about the rest of it? i know that its completely wrong but don't know how to fix it

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand your if-statement.  Why would you fail everything above 16?  Basically half of your loop iterations will go through the assert.fail logic.

Comment: how can I write the - "Use a For Loop to loop through all integer values from 1 to 32. Use a Try Catch to deal with not having a key in the Dictionary"?

Comment: What is the actual language you're trying to use here?

Comment: I can only assume you're actually trying to use VBA here.

Comment: Visual Basic.. I am new and really confused

Comment: Dictionary objects have .exists methods.  `myDictionary.Exists(loopCounter)`  I would suggest though, that you back up and start fresh.  Break your program down into components and test each one.  I can see several areas of your program that would break it.

Comment: I think that the first part - the dictionary itself is correct. I don't understand how to write a For loop for the dictionary.. any examples?

Comment: My previous post was straight forward.  `for i = 1 to 32 myDictionary.Exists(i)  Next`  I can promise you that your code is broken.  Compartmentalize it, and test the components.